# HTML editor with html encoding built in

Tags: notepad++

I am now using Notepad++ as seems to be often suggested here for basic html & css editing.  Only thing missing is a method to HTML Encode pasted in text.  Is there a way to do this in Notepad++ or do I need to look for a different editor which dos this?  If so any suggestions, I have used Komposer in the past which was ok, is there anything better out there now.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the HTML syntax highlighting on pasted code? Notepad++ does this, click 'Language' on the menu bar.

Comment: No what I meant is I want to paste text in there and have all the &s converted to &amp; etc

Comment: Related: [Can we decode URL with Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430523/can-we-decode-url-with-notepad)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes there is a plug-in for that (I am running version 6.9.2).

HTML TAG did the trick for me, here are the steps I did to get it to work:

1. install the plugin from Notepad++
   [image: Plugins->Plugin Manager->Show Plugin Manager]
   [image: Find HTML TAG]

sadly, there are more steps (at least for me!)

2. Now I had to download the actual plugin: [HTML TAG](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/?source=navbar) and find HTML Tag and download it
3. unzip the tag and then place it into 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins'

`&lt;HTML&gt;
 &lt;BODY&gt;
 &lt;TABLE&gt;&lt;TR&gt;&lt;TD&gt;&lt;/TD&gt;&lt;/TR&gt;&lt;/TABLE&gt;
 &lt;/BODY&gt; &lt;/HTML&gt;`

`<HTML>
<BODY>
<TABLE><TR><TD></TD></TR></TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>`

it will also do the

```
test&=3543
```

to

```
test&amp;=3543
```

I updated this on 9/8/16 to amend the link, since this requires a link, if that link goes bad please tell me in the comments and I will delete out this answer or find the new one.

Comment: Thanks Harrison, works a treat.  I had the same problem as you with the .ini missing and downloaded it manually, all then works ok.

Comment: @NickC, terrific! there are also a host of XML formatting tools (which have come in handy for me).  if the answer helped, feel free to mark it as the answer!