# Can we decode URL with Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am currently using this site `http://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html` to decode code like.

`http%3A%2F%2Fh.mysite.com%2F007%2FYRM-CD-9` **to** `http://h.mysite.com/007/YRM-CD-9` by using URL Decode on that decoding site.

I was wondering if this can be done via Notepad++.

Comment: A workaround solution [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/5249d0f2#54f1)

Comment: Thanks, I will need to read on how to install it.

Comment: TextFX only provides `Convert/Encode URI component`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to PiLHA.

1. Download the [jN](https://github.com/sieukrem/jn-npp-plugin/releases) plugin.
2. Place files from Zip to Plugin folder of Notepad++ in `C:\Programs Files\Notepad++\plugins`.
3. Save Code below as `URLENDECODE.js` and save it to `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\jN\includes`.
4. Restart Notepad++.

Code:

```js
var URLDecoderEncoder = Editor.addMenu('URL-Encoding/Decoding');
URLDecoderEncoder.addItem({
    text: 'Encode',
    cmd: function() {
        var unencoded = Editor.currentView.text;
        var encoded = encodeURIComponent(unencoded);
        Editor.currentView.text = encoded;
    }
});
URLDecoderEncoder.addItem({
    text: 'Decode',
    cmd: function() {
        var encoded = Editor.currentView.text;
        var unencoded = decodeURIComponent(encoded);
        Editor.currentView.text = unencoded;
    }
});
URLDecoderEncoder.addItem({
    text: 'Decode multi-pass (7x)',
    cmd: function() {
        var encoded = Editor.currentView.text;
        var unencoded_pass1 = decodeURIComponent(encoded);
        var unencoded_pass2 = decodeURIComponent(unencoded_pass1);
        var unencoded_pass3 = decodeURIComponent(unencoded_pass2);
        var unencoded_pass4 = decodeURIComponent(unencoded_pass3);
        var unencoded_pass5 = decodeURIComponent(unencoded_pass4);
        var unencoded_pass6 = decodeURIComponent(unencoded_pass5);
        var unencoded = decodeURIComponent(unencoded_pass6);
        Editor.currentView.text = unencoded;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Only thing It won't record Macros. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a heads up, the JN plugin will add *lots* of new menu items, so if you don't like that you might want to avoid it or customize JN.

Comment: This JN plugin is a great tool! Thanks!
Are you familiar with some other nice scripts to add to the JN? Where and where can i find them?

Comment: By the way, to remove all unneeded menus you can move the scripts to  'disabled' folder ('plugins\jN\includes\disabled')

Comment: And another issue with the plugin is that it causes a very annoying error everytime I open or switch to a .ps1 document (powershell).

Comment: This answer is a bit Overkill. See the answer from Jason69 for the built-in solution if you don't need the extra functionality and menu items that jN adds

Answer (score 147):

In Notepad++ under <kbd>Plugins</kbd> => <kbd>MIME Tools</kbd> you will find <kbd>URL Encode</kbd> and <kbd>URL Decode</kbd>.

Comment: I knew I'd seen that somewhere.

Comment: Plus sign doesn't get converted to space it seems when you do URL decode through MIME tools plugin.

Comment: It has been expired. No support for version 7

Comment: It's there in version 7.3.3. Not sure if it came bundled with installer or I installed separately.

Comment: It's bundled in 7.5.3.