# Automatically decode URLs in Notepad++

Tags: url, macros, notepad++, decode

I am working with a lot of URL links which I need to decode.
I want to write a macro (or use any other method, really, whatever is easiest) attached to a keyboard shortcut which will automatically decode the urls into readable text.
For example, I want to press CTRL+A and have the result be that all %20 instances are replaced with a space, all & are replaced with an ENTER (\n, going down one row), all %27 replaced with ', etc.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Notepad++?
So far I have been manually changing at least 2-3 codes each time, but it's maddening as I have hundreds of such URLs to work with.
The URLs are sent to me automatically one at a time by a "report broken link" function and arrive as an openURL, example attached below.

Thank you!

URL examples:

```
ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&ctx_enc=info%3Aofi%2Fenc%3AUTF-8&url_ver=Z39.88-2004&rfr_id=info%3Asid%2FElsevier%3ASD&svc_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Asch_svc&rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Ajournal&rft.aulast=GILABERTE&rft.auinit=Y&rft.date=2014&rft.issn=00017310&rft.volume=105&rft.issue=3&rft.spage=253&rft.epage=262&rft.title=Actas%20Dermo-Sifiliogr%C3%A1ficas&rft.atitle=Realidades%20y%20retos%20de%20la%20fotoprotecci%C3%B3n%20en%20la%20infancia&rft_id=info%3Adoi%2F10.1016%2Fj.ad.2013.05.004
```

And this is how it looks like after changing & and %20:

```
ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004
ctx_enc=info%3Aofi%2Fenc%3AUTF-8
url_ver=Z39.88-2004
rfr_id=info%3Asid%2FElsevier%3ASD
svc_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Asch_svc
rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Ajournal
rft.aulast=GILABERTE
rft.auinit=Y
rft.date=2014
rft.issn=00017310
rft.volume=105
rft.issue=3
rft.spage=253
rft.epage=262
rft.title=Actas Dermo-Sifiliogr%C3%A1ficas
rft.atitle=Realidades y retos de la fotoprotecci%C3%B3n en la infancia
rft_id=info%3Adoi%2F10.1016%2Fj.ad.2013.05.004
```

As you can see this is much more readable for extracting details, but there are still many more codes in there that need changing.

Comment: Where reside the URL links - many as a list in `one` text files or many text files or many HTML files? Please give some examples by editing your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Can we decode URL with Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430523/can-we-decode-url-with-notepad?rq=1)

Comment: Edited to add requested information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have your single URL or some more in a text file line by line you'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Plugins > MIME Tools > URL Decode
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `&`
- Replace with: `\n`
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

If you really need a shortcut like e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> you may use:

**Macro > Start Recording** the steps from above and **Save Currently Recorded Macro** when finished.

The snaps below show your sample source and the resulting text.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what I do (though I reach this menu by simply using CTRL+F and choosing the replace tab).
But I'll try the MACRO and see if that works. If so I'll mark this as the answer :)
Thanx!

Comment: Well I've recorded the macro and saved it, and it seems to work great!

Comment: CTRL+H is because the replace tab is simply selected in one step - but this depends on the user preference.

Comment: Just an update - for some reason, the macro recording doesn't record the URL decoding command.
What I did was, unfortunately, record all the commands by hand via find&replace, then saved the macro with a shortcut.
I don't know why the URL decoding isn't recorded.